# Ranking Duplicate String Values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, formula, ranking

I have a spreadsheet with string values and need to create a column with the rank (without using the rank function) of the duplicate values from another column.
Please see below for example of the desired outcome where Dupe_Rank is the created column.

Thanks!

| Name | Dupe_Rank |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| John | 2 |
| Dave | 1 |
| John | 3 |
| Bill | 1 |
| Dave | 2 |

Comment: Check the aggregate() function.

Answer (score 1):

let's say "Name" starts from column 'A' and row 2 as in below figure:

[image]

then add this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)
```

to cells below Dupe_Rank and then drag(or copy-paste) this formula to all the cells

[image]